# React-Typescript-useTranslation: Parameter declaration expected. TS1138

Tags: react-typescript

I am using React-typescript for my app. For my app, I used [useTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start). useTranslation works fine inside the functional component. I have created validated custom error handler which is outside of the functional component. when I used [useTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start) logic, it does work and shows me: Parameter declaration expected. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
const validate = (i: IFormStateValues<IData>, t: any) => {
  const errors: IFormStateErrors<IData> = {};

  if (!i?.name) {
    errors.name = {t(`notValidLengthError`)}; //ERROR:Parameter declaration expected
  }
  return errors;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to fix it is by spreading `t`

```
const validate = (i: IFormStateValues<IData>, t: any) => {
  const errors: IFormStateErrors<IData> = {};

  if (!i?.name) {
    errors.name = {...t(`notValidLengthError`)}; //ERROR:Parameter declaration expected
  }
  return errors;
};
```

but Ad I do not know what t is, I’ll tell you what is happenings, typescript and I have the same question

The property name of errors is been initialed by an Object that does not have any properties I am assuming t is a function that is returning a value, but errors.name is an empty object. There for TS does not like that. setting a value to an empty object with no property where to set the new invomming value.